# Pure HTML input type text validation using pattern

Tags: html, validation

Recently I tried alot but I still unable to figure how should I able to validation for my text field. I hope I can get some help from here, my questions is I want to validate input text field only accept A-Z a-z 0-9 and space within word. And at least one char or number.
For example, "abc def" , "abc092", "abcdef" 
Only in HTML input tag element .
I tried this
 but this pattern unable to fullfil my requirements.

### the pattern i want to achieve is

1) abc def
2) abcdef
3) abc123
4) a1b2c3 d4e5
5) allow to have empty space within words

### the pattern i dont want to accept is

1) empty string
2) no alot of whitespace at the begining or end of the string
3) no bracket and etc special characters

Comment: Please show exactly what you have tried. Preferably as a [mcve]

Comment: Is there minimum string length? I.E. should "A" match

Comment: Helllo buddy why you deleted your Question about the JSON obj conversion!!??

Comment: Open a new question  i finished the code

Comment: hello......................

Comment: https://codepen.io/vkv88/pen/ZEGLbpR?editors=0010       this is what you want✌  **I  Used  Recursion**

Comment: i was hoping i get accepted answer 

Comment: @You Unknown ..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="text" pattern="^\w+([\w ]*\w)*$">
```

Basically the break down is this:

`\w+` - Select a word character ("A-z0-9") one or more times

`()*` - Select what's in here 0 or more times, which is

`[\w ]*\w` - Select a word character or space one or more times followed by another word character

No leading or trailing white space allowed. Only word characters allowed and internal spaces.

For some unit tests and breakdown of the regex see: https://regex101.com/r/7UnL9J/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pattern attribute with regex but it is supported only  in HTML 5. 
Like this  " id="username" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+"

Check the below link for more information
https://html.com/attributes/input-pattern/#Username_Patterns

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+">
```

Comment: for this pattern pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+" <--- this allow empty whitespaces. how can i validate it if it's a empty whitespaces?